# This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions

Tags: sql-server

I'm new with MS SQL. How will I simplify this query in the case statement?

The part where the case statement happen. I want to count unique new accounts

Example:

> 'JAN' 234 - Accounts 'FEB' 20  - New Accounts result will be (234 +
> 20 = 254) 254 will appear in 'FEB'

```
    SELECT DISTINCT T0.Year,
T0.[Channel YTD],
T0.Month,
CASE [Month]
    WHEN 'JAN' THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Buying Accounts])) FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD WHERE Year = T0.Year AND Month IN ('JAN') AND [Combined Name] = T0.[Combined Name])
    WHEN 'FEB' THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Buying Accounts])) FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD WHERE Year = T0.Year AND Month IN ('JAN','FEB') AND [Combined Name] = T0.[Combined Name])
    WHEN 'MAR' THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Buying Accounts])) FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD WHERE Year = T0.Year AND Month IN ('JAN','FEB','MAR') AND [Combined Name] = T0.[Combined Name])
    WHEN 'APR' THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Buying Accounts])) FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD WHERE Year = T0.Year AND Month IN ('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR') AND [Combined Name] = T0.[Combined Name])
    WHEN 'MAY' THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Buying Accounts])) FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD WHERE Year = T0.Year AND Month IN ('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY') AND [Combined Name] = T0.[Combined Name])
    WHEN 'JUN' THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Buying Accounts])) FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD WHERE Year = T0.Year AND Month IN ('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN') AND [Combined Name] = T0.[Combined Name])
    WHEN 'JUL' THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Buying Accounts])) FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD WHERE Year = T0.Year AND Month IN ('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL') AND [Combined Name] = T0.[Combined Name])
    WHEN 'AUG' THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Buying Accounts])) FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD WHERE Year = T0.Year AND Month IN ('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG') AND [Combined Name] = T0.[Combined Name])
    WHEN 'SEP' THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Buying Accounts])) FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD WHERE Year = T0.Year AND Month IN ('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP') AND [Combined Name] = T0.[Combined Name])
    WHEN 'OCT' THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Buying Accounts])) FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD WHERE Year = T0.Year AND Month IN ('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT') AND [Combined Name] = T0.[Combined Name])
    WHEN 'NOV' THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Buying Accounts])) FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD WHERE Year = T0.Year AND Month IN ('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV') AND [Combined Name] = T0.[Combined Name])
    WHEN 'DEC' THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Buying Accounts])) FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD WHERE Year = T0.Year AND Month IN ('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC') AND [Combined Name] = T0.[Combined Name])
    ELSE 0
    END AS [Buying Account YTD],
T0.[TPP Channel Type],
T0.[Combined Name]
FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD T0
WHERE Year =2021
AND [Buying Accounts] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You're essentially looking for a monthly running total of count, partitioned by channel and name. You should be able to find examples - there are a few ways to do this,.

Comment: How is your question's title relate to the query ?

Comment: @Squirrel this is the error message when I ran the query The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.

Comment: @StuartLC Yes that's what I want to do, but how am I suppose to do that? can I have example code?

Comment: You seems to have another question as well. Please focus on one issue at a time. What is the version of `SQL Server` are you using ? and have you applied the all the service pack ? Please edit your question and focus on one issue

Comment: @Squirrel the version of my MS SQL is : Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB4019088) - 13.0.1742.0 (X64)   Jul  5 2017 23:41:17   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: )

Comment: @Squirrel okay to clarify my question, In the given query, when I ran it I got the error like what I used in my title, I only copied the full error message earlier.

Comment: You are using RTM. Applied the latest service pack / CU and try

Comment: @Squirrel where can i find the latest service pack for my MS SQL?

Comment: [SQL Server 2016 build versions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3177312-sql-server-2016-build-versions-d6cd8e5f-4aa3-20ac-f38f-8faef950840f)

Comment: @Squirrel Thank you! I will update my service pack then I will return if this solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window aggregates to do this. Unfortunately, there is no `COUNT (DISTINCT` window aggregate, but we can simulate it with `DENSE_RANK` and `MAX`.

You need to order by the month number. Since you don't appear to have such a column, you need to fabricate it.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    T0.Year,
    T0.[Channel YTD],
    T0.Month,
    MAX(rnk) over (PARTITION BY [Combined Name], [Year]) AS [Buying Account YTD],
    T0.[TPP Channel Type],
    T0.[Combined Name]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Combined Name], [Year] ORDER BY [Buying Accounts]) rnk
    FROM VW_CHPerMonth_ChannelYTD T0
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT CASE [Month]
          WHEN JAN THEN 1
          WHEN FEB THEN 2
          WHEN MAR THEN 3
          WHEN APR THEN 4
          WHEN MAY THEN 5
          WHEN JUN THEN 6
          WHEN JUL THEN 7
          WHEN AUG THEN 8
          WHEN SEP THEN 9
          WHEN OCT THEN 10
          WHEN NOV THEN 11
          ELSE 12
          END
    ) v(MonthNumber)
    WHERE Year = 2021
    AND [Buying Accounts] IS NOT NULL
) T0
```